# How to combine/re-writes 'minute' in pandas.to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, data-science

How to combine/re-writes 'minute' in pandas.to_datetime?
My data frame looks like below:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
               'years' : df.year,
               'months': df.Month,
               'days'  : df.DayofMonth,
               'hours' : df.hour,
               'mins'  : df.min

                })
pd.to_datetime(df_2).head()
```

Result:

> ValueError: extra keys have been passed to the datetime assemblage: [mins]

Comment: [edit] your post to add/modify data

Comment: Typo of `'mins'  : df.min` instead of `'mins'  : df.mins`

Answer (score 1):

The new name, to be recognized by `pandas.to_datetime` should be `minute/minutes` and you need column `mins` (not `min` which is a method) from `df`

```
'mins': df.min      # old
'minutes': df.mins  # new
```

---

Also that seems to be only a renaming, so you can use `DataFrame.rename`

```
df_2 = df.rename(columns={'DayofMonth': 'days', 'mins': 'minutes', 'sec': 'seconds'})
x = pd.to_datetime(df_2).head()

0   2015-08-21 19:34:00
1   2015-04-20 15:48:00
2   2015-09-02 14:22:00
3   2015-11-25 10:15:00
4   2015-10-07 18:28:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It's working as expected.                                                                                                                                                                        
Have renamed my DataFrame column keys to [‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’, ‘second’]

Comment: @Suresh you're welcome, you can think about accepting so (green tick on left) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html -->Examples

> Examples

Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys can be common abbreviations like [‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’, ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘us’, ‘ns’]) or plurals of the same

Comment: Documentation is ok but an actual solution is better. Or include the relevant examples.